# Increase size of randomly created encrypted swap

Tags: swap, luks, dm-crypt

Ubuntu 18.04 is by default creating a random encrypted swap during each boot using dm-crypt/Swap encryption. For me, this is creating a 1gb swap but I cannot find where to increase the size of the swap it creates on each boot. How can we increase the swap size allocated during each boot? I do not want to switch to a static swapfile.

from **/etc/crypttab**:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=aba1b825-a77b-4384-a40f-fdc6fdaaced0 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

from **/etc/fstab**:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the size of the swap partition? That should be all you need to do.

Comment: Also note the random swap isn't using luks. You can still have for example a swap in a lvm in luks, but then it's probably no more a *random* encrypted swap.

Comment: AFAIK there is no permanent swap partition. Updated question with file contents.